# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: g is undefined on bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How to fix error `Uncaught TypeError: g is undefined` on bootstrap datepicker? I tried to make date picker using bootstrap-datepicker lib and I stuck on this error

[image: Errot]

What makes me confused is that in other projects in the same environment, everything works fine and there are no problems. Only I found error on this project, i don't know why

I already import a css

```
<link href="{{ asset('template/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and js lib

```
<script src="{{ asset('template/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
```

and my page js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#periode_kontrak_start').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() });
});

$(document).on('change keyup keydown', '#periode_kontrak_start', function() {
    //
}).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#periode_kontrak_end').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
});
```

But when I try, always get an error. How to fix this error?

Comment: the [online](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) has those undefined problems